# Negotiating about salary

Tags: salary

I got a contract for 24 months at my company. That time is nearly over and now I want to have an unlimited contract. As far as I can judge my output, I am doing a great job here and nobody ever complained about me. Would it be inappropriate to ask for a significant raise at this point?

Comment: matter of feeling & company culture. One of the things to remember is that "unlimited" is already an advantage, and they might think it's enough.

Comment: Editted to try to prevent closure.  If you are unhappy with the edit please feel free to roll it back.

Comment: You are asking for an "unlimited" (I think you mean "on-going" or "automatic renewal" contract) and also a raise. Is that right? Are you asking about building raises into the new contract?

Comment: I ment unlimited contract like there is no end date. The better term might be 'for an unlimited period', i am sorry for my bad english. Thanks Jim and  all people that helped me finding a decission.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, ask for a raise if you think you're worth one. 2 years experience at the job is worth a bit. I'd actually ask for more than 10%. But that depends on how high you rate your skills and worth.

If you have been there for 24 months without a raise in that time, then you're definitely due for one in the normal run of things. But all negotiations are exactly that, negotiations, your task is to sell your work for as much as you can get.

Comment: Thanks. I once got a raise, like everybody gets a raise about 2,5% each year automatically. I think i won't ask for raise at that time. I will go for the unlimeted contract. I don't want them to fire me and look for another job again. This company is quite okay.

Answer (score 0):

It's not inappropriate, but you should do research on what salary you could be paid in your local market generally for your type of work.

That could be research on job sites, meeting with recruiters, discussions with friends, or similar activities.

You might find you're worth a 20% raise, so don't necessarily use your current salary as your absolute benchmark.